# Google colab, tensorflow, eager execution does not work

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I need to be able to turn a tensor to a numpy array.
This brings me to the issue of eager execution.

I am working in google colab notebook with tensorflow version 2.12.0.
CPU.

In some places I read, that eager execution is enabled by default in versions 2+
This does not seem to be true, because `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns false, and `mytensor.numpy()` does not exist.

So, I tried to turn it on manually with `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()`, but get an error:

`ValueError: tf.enable_eager_execution must be called at program startup.`

Even though I am running it right after I import tf.

It seems, that there is no way to simply turn tensor to numpy array or turn on eager execution in colab.

Please help.

Attaching screenshots as requested:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code itself? It should be True unless you are doing things in graph mode or using tf.function.

Comment: @Frightera Here you go, updated

Comment: This is weird, did you try running `tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()` after the import statement?

Comment: @Frightera Yes, I did. Tried it before the print statements as well

Comment: Did you install any other packages that can create a conflict with TF dependencies? If no, it should be something about that Colab session, deleting the runtime and getting fresh one can help because no one can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Nope, nothing like this. However, I just restarted runtime, and somehow magically it is all eagerly executing.

Answer (score 0):

It appears restarting runtime solves this problem. Not sure how or why.